# Gwibber Problems

Tags: gwibber

I have configured my facebook account in Gwibber since I installed Ubuntu 12.10.

Until a few days I started to notice that the program does not refresh and display notifications, when opened gwibber interface goes blank and not updated. I read in forums that could be the proxy settings or interfering with its operation but everything is correct.

Get to the end to try on another computer than with ubuntu 12.10 and gwibber but to my surprise it is the same.

Not that I make gwibber work I thought it was ubuntu but on another pc than just occurred, not to do, that I can recommend another program or how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a workaround here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1088775

Comment: Good day to all, as I had mentioned earlier Gwibber not show any information of facebook despite being authorized from the account and entered the data correctly in ubuntu.

After searching for a while on Google I found the solution to this failure on the next page:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-facebook-not-working-with-gwibber.html

Just to follow step by step guide (pretty simple by the way) in which they are everything to indicate that gwibber working again.

Really works are not left without testing.

salu2

Comment: @user116837 This blog post references the bug entry that I have you the link to also and just replicated the workaround that I posted to that bug entry, so this is exactly the fix that I developed and you can accept this answer as the right one. ;-)